# Unable to click on a popup with id's using selenium webdriver and ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is the code i am using

```
def self.yes_publish
      sleep 5
      driver.find_element(:id, 'dialogConfirmChanges-publishButton').displayed?
      WAIT.until { driver.find_element(:id, 'dialogConfirmChanges-publishButton') }.click        
      puts driver.find_element(:id, 'embed-left-center-part').displayed?
     end
```

But i am unable to click on it. This id works fine in irb.
I get an error modal dialog present, as webdriver is unable to locate element it closes to window after a particular timeout. 
This popup is to publish changes made on a page.

```
xpath = .//*[@id='dialogConfirmChanges-publishButton']
```

Comment: Can you give the relevant html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`switch_to`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#switch_to-instance_method) method to deal with the pop-up. Look at the documentation of [**`JavaScript dialogs`**](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#JavaScript_dialogs) :

You can use webdriver to handle Javascript alert(), prompt() and confirm() dialogs. The API for all three is the same.

***Note:*** At this time alert handling is only available in Firefox and IE (or in those browsers through the remote server), and only alerts that are generated post onload can be captured.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://mysite.com/page_with_alert.html"

driver.find_element(:name, 'element_with_alert_javascript').click
a = driver.switch_to.alert
if a.text == 'A value you are looking for'
  a.dismiss
else
  a.accept
end
```

**EDIT**

As per the comment box HTML given by you..I think below should work :

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@id='dia‌​logConfirmChanges-publishButton']").click
```

Comment: This is the HTML code <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
<button id="dialogConfirmChanges-publishButton" class="otherButtonClass ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="button" role="button" aria-disabled="false">

Comment: Its not working webdriver isn't able to click on that element

Comment: Did you get any pop-up window?

Comment: @TheRookie Try this `driver.find_element(:xpath,"//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/button[@id='dialogConfirmChanges-publishButton']").click`